# Problema al enviar formulario a PHP con addEventListener en HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html5, phpmyadmin

Recientemente comencé a aprender `php` e intento crear una página de registro sencilla en `html` usando `phpmyadmin` y `xampp`, pero me encuentro con un problema.

Tengo un formulario para crear una "cuenta" en una base de datos donde en el archivo `html` está el formulario para enviar la información, lo que hice fue crear un par de entradas de texto y creé dos botones, uno para validar y cambiar la información para que se envíe en un formato específico y el otro, un `submit`, envía esta a través del método `post` para enviar la información a un archivo `php` y esta agregarla a la base de datos.

El problema es que agregué un `addEventListener` para validar la información. Lo que pasa es que si está el `addEventListener`, el archivo `php` no recibe la información de los formularios. Lo intenté con `get` y `post`, pero en ambos pasa lo mismo. El `addEventListener` evita que se envíe la información al archivo `php`.

¿Qué debo hacer?

**Este es el Código del HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script defer src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="reg.php" method="post">
        Ingrese su nombre:
        <input type="text" id="acc" name="acce">
        <br>
        Ingrese su telefono:
        <input type="text" id="tel" name="tele">
        <hr>
        <p id="info">Para continuar primero valide la informacion</p>
        <input id="Acceder" type="submit" value="Crear cuenta">
    </form>
    <p id="v">Validar</p>
    <a href="registro.html"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```js
let val = document.getElementById("v");
let acc = document.getElementById("acc");
let tel = document.getElementById("tel");
val.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if ( (acc.value && tel.value  ) == "" ) {
        alert("Hay uno o más valores en blanco")
    } else if ( (tel.value*0) != 0 ) {
        alert("Debe ingresar numeros solamente en el area de telefono")
    } else {
        info.textContent = "Se realizaron los cambios necesarios, ya se puede registrar";
        let str = acc.value.toUpperCase();
        str = str.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
        acc.value = str;
        val.disabled = true;
        acc.disabled = true;
        tel.disabled = true;
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```php
<?php
if($_POST){
    $acc=$_POST['acce'];
    echo "Nombre: ".$acc;
}
?>
```

Usando el código que te comparto, pueden copiarlo y pegarlo en el archivo `html`, `js` y `php` correspondiente para verificar esto.

Si se presiona el botón "**verificar**" primero y luego "**Crear cuenta**" la información no se envía al `php` pero si solo se presiona el botón "**Crear cuenta**" envía la información correctamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para validar los campos del formulario tienes estas opciones:

- El atributo `required` de `HTML` que no permite enviar campos vacíos
- Una validación en `JS` que se ejecute en el evento `oninput` del campo de teléfono
- Una expresión regular que solo permita números

```js
function validarCaracteres(valor) {
  //Se define una variable que contiene una expresión regular para permitir sólo números
  let numeros = /^[0-9]+$/;
  //Validar los caracteres del campo teléfono
  if (valor.match(numeros)) {
    console.log('Campo válido');
  } else {
    alert('Debe ingresar numeros solamente en el area de telefono');
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script defer src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="reg.php" method="post">
    Ingrese su nombre:
    <input type="text" id="acc" name="acce" required>
    <br> Ingrese su telefono:
    <input type="text" id="tel" name="tele" oninput="validarCaracteres(this.value)" required>
    <hr>
    <p id="info">Para continuar primero valide la informacion</p>
    <input id="Acceder" type="submit" value="Crear cuenta">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

El ejemplo tiene funciones básicas, el resto lo debes acomodar a tu proyecto. *Y recuerda validar también del lado del servidor*.